# Netty lags for a few seconds before shutting down

Tags: netty

Iv been doing network programming for a while and recently converted one of my projects to netty.  Iv been bothered a lot by the fact that unlike with my original program, the client will freeze for about 3-5 seconds before closing, enough to make me end up force terminating it everytime because I don't want to wait for it.  Is this normal for netty? am I doing something wrong?

main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    final SslContext sslCtx = SslContext.newClientContext(InsecureTrustManagerFactory.INSTANCE);

    EventLoopGroup group = new NioEventLoopGroup();
    try {
        Bootstrap b = new Bootstrap();
        b.group(group)
         .channel(NioSocketChannel.class)
         .handler(new NetworkInitializer(sslCtx));
        // Start the connection attempt.
         ch = b.connect(HOST, PORT).sync().channel();

        //sends the clients name to the server
        askname();


    //loop just does some simple gl stuff and gameplay updating, posted below
        while(running){loop();
        if (Display.isCloseRequested()){


            running = false;
            if (lastWriteFuture != null) {
                lastWriteFuture.sync();
            }    //tells the server to shut down
            write("9");
            ch.closeFuture().sync();
            group.shutdownGracefully();
            System.out.println("herro der");
            break;
        }
        }
    } finally {
        group.shutdownGracefully();

        // The connection is closed automatically on shutdown.
    }
}
```

loop class:

```
    private static void loop() {
    GL11.glClear(GL11.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    //main update method for my game.  does calculations and stuff.  I can post it if neccisary but its kinda big.
    SpaceState.update();
    Display.update();
    Display.sync(60);
}
```

Comment: Java 8 by any chance ? Seen the same thing. Not netty specific, and not observed with Java 7/6 with same code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`group.shutdownGracefully();` by default waits for about 3 seconds until all pending tasks are executed completely before it terminates itself.  You can specify a different timeout value, but too small value has the risk of getting `RejectedExecutionException`.  If you are sure your application has no business left with the event loop group, you can specify a very small value to terminate it immediately.